# PHP intval in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

It is safe to use intval:

```
... WHERE id = " . intval($_POST['input']) . " AND ...
```

instead mysqli_real_escape_string:

```
... WHERE id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['input']) . "' AND ...
```

for prevent any sql errors, or injection attacks?

Comment: Frankly you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: If you are expecting an **integer** - the answer is yes, however it's much better to use prepared statements.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, can you provide an example of sqlinj that will pass the `intval`?

Comment: No @Dekel, I cannot. Actually `intval()` could be very safe, but just have unintended consequences.

Comment: I agree, but the question was "is it safe?", so I think the answer is "yes, but you **should** use prepared..." :)

Comment: My comment has been sanitized fro your protection :) @Dekel

Comment: haha :) great !